# Autofill showing in Material UI Textfield and Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, autofill

Material-UI Textfield and Autocomplete display Autofill dropdown when clicking on them. I tried using

```
inputProps={{
    ...params.inputProps,
    autoComplete: "off",
 }}
```

in the textfield and

```
inputProps={{
     autoComplete: "off",
    }}
```

in the Autocomplete as well as adding the autoComplete="off" prop in the Textfield. However, it doesn't always display, as it works at first then it randomly starts displaying the Autofill dropdown.

I tried including a screenshot of it but it isn't capturing the autofill dropdown in the image.

Another thing I tried is

```
  inputProps={{
    autocomplete: 'new-password',
    form: {
      autocomplete: 'off',
    },
  }}
```

but it also works at first then it starts displaying the Autofill dropdown again.

Comment: the autocomplete feature could be related to browser.

Comment: @MukulSharma when we turn off autofill from the browser it completely disappears. Is there a way to completely disable the feature on our website without having to go into the browser or is turning it off from the browser the only way?

Comment: Working through a similar issue and am going to assume you are using chrome based on your explanation. The only way I've found to address this is turning off the chrome autofill settings for "Addresses". You can find this in settings then search for autofill